# How to update MySQL faster by XML data?

Tags: python, mysql, sql

XMl has 5000 records of 'product', table in MySQL has 6000 records of 'product', not all of xml records has equivalent in database. I want to put data from xml to mysql quicker. How to do it? The time it takes to finish running is 11 seconds now.

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="",
                         user="",
                         passwd="",
                         db="")
cur = db.cursor()

DOMTree = minidom.parse(file.xml)
cNodes = DOMTree.childNodes

for i in cNodes[0].getElementsByTagName("product"):
    y = i.getElementsByTagName("code")[0].childNodes[0].toxml()
    z = i.getElementsByTagName("available")[0].childNodes[0].toxml()

    cur.execute("UPDATE product SET stock=%s WHERE ean=%s", (z, y))
db.commit()
```

Comment: Your Question is not Clear, you mean "Records" instead of "Positions" and what do you mean by faster? Faster/Quicker doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Executemany** is your friend, instead of repeatedly executing the command in your for loop, you can collect all Data and push them at once.

```
data = [
  ('A', 'blabla'),
  ('B', 'test1'),
  ('C', 'test2'),
]
stmt = "UPDATE product SET stock=%s WHERE ean=%s"
cur.executemany(stmt, data)
```

More info here:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-executemany.html